# xsltproc not recognizing fx:function (any more)

Tags: xslt, debian, exslt

I have a strange effect. I use xalanj and xsltproc and I think most scripts worked on both (time ago). However, since a while, xslt scripts with {http://exslt.org/functions}function do no longer work in xsltproc. This is debian 7.9.

Code snippet

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:yz="http://www.hegny.de/xxyy"
    xmlns:fx="http://exslt.org/functions">

...
<fx:function name="yz:format3">
    <xsl:param name="x"/>
    <xsl:choose>
...
```

will work fine with xalanj but xsltproc will complain

```
compilation error: file /home/hegny/prog/syno_recording/xmltv_text.xsl line 67 element param
element param only allowed within a template, variable or param
```

(line 67 being the param under the fx:function)

Also, when calling `xsltproc --dumpextensions` will show

```
Registered XSLT Extensions
--------------------------
Registered Extension Functions:
...(nothing containing exslt.org/functions)...

Registered Extension Elements:
{http://exslt.org/functions}result
{http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/}test
{http://exslt.org/common}document

Registered Extension Modules:
http://icl.com/saxon
http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/
http://exslt.org/functions
```

will indicate that it knows about fx:result which belongs to the exslt functions stuff, but not about fx:function - what sense would that make? Anyone found out how to get the fx:function (back?) to work? - Thanks

Comment: I think your XSLT root element should declare `extension-element-prefixes="fx"`, no? Whether that is the sole solution I am not sure as I don't use `xsltproc` much.

Comment: You bet I should! - make an answer and get full reward. I thought I tried that too but then again, now it works in xsltproc with functions .. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use extension elements like `fx:function`, make sure your stylesheet declares the namespace of the extension element as well as declares `extension-element-prefixes="fx"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` respectively `xsl:transform` root element of your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinHonnen, really should have seen it myself